# How to rotate normal using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to extrude the selected edges using geometry nodes where the Normal node is setting the offset. How can I extrude the edges parallel to the faces that the edges are connected to?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$\hspace{15pt}$With the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) operation between the normal and the normalized vector made by the edge's vertices you can get a unit vector orthogonal to both the face normal and the edge. Sometimes it will point towards the face, and in these cases they need to be negated, we can do that by checking if it points towards the face position from the edge position using the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) operation and negating if it does.

[image: node tree]